# Pandas DataFrame: replace all values in a column, based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple DataFrame like the following:

|  | Team | First Season | Total Games |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Dallas Cowboys | 1960 | 894 |
| 1 | Chicago Bears | 1920 | 1357 |
| 2 | Green Bay Packers | 1921 | 1339 |
| 3 | Miami Dolphins | 1966 | 792 |
| 4 | Baltimore Ravens | 1996 | 326 |
| 5 | San Francisco 49ers | 1950 | 1003 |

I want to select all values from the `First Season` column and replace those that are over 1990 by 1. In this example, only Baltimore Ravens would have the 1996 replaced by 1 (keeping the rest of the data intact).

I have used the following:

```
df.loc[(df['First Season'] > 1990)] = 1
```

But, it replaces all the values in that row by 1, not just the values in the 'First Season' column.

How can I replace just the values from that column?

Answer (score 448, accepted):

You need to select that column:

```
In [41]:
df.loc[df['First Season'] > 1990, 'First Season'] = 1
df

Out[41]:
                 Team  First Season  Total Games
0      Dallas Cowboys          1960          894
1       Chicago Bears          1920         1357
2   Green Bay Packers          1921         1339
3      Miami Dolphins          1966          792
4    Baltimore Ravens             1          326
5  San Franciso 49ers          1950         1003
```

So the syntax here is:

```
df.loc[<mask>(here mask is generating the labels to index) , <optional column(s)> ]
```

You can check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) and also the [10 minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#selection-by-label) which shows the semantics

**EDIT**

If you want to generate a boolean indicator then you can just use the boolean condition to generate a boolean Series and cast the dtype to `int` this will convert `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` respectively:

```
In [43]:
df['First Season'] = (df['First Season'] > 1990).astype(int)
df

Out[43]:
                 Team  First Season  Total Games
0      Dallas Cowboys             0          894
1       Chicago Bears             0         1357
2   Green Bay Packers             0         1339
3      Miami Dolphins             0          792
4    Baltimore Ravens             1          326
5  San Franciso 49ers             0         1003
```

Answer (score 91):

A bit late to the party but still - I prefer using numpy where:

```
import numpy as np
df['First Season'] = np.where(df['First Season'] > 1990, 1, df['First Season'])
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution for overwriting column values conditionally, but based on an other column's value, like this:

    df['col1'] = np.where(df['id'] == '318431682259014', 'NEW', df['col1'])

This was the solution for it.

Comment: I am trying to do this for multiple conditions like this, but I keep getting `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. What I'm trying to do is basically `df['A'] = np.where(df['B'] in some_values, df['A']*2, df['A]`. Does anybody have an idea on this?

Comment: There is a built-in `where` method in pandas now, and it is compared to `np.where` in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where

Comment: I was playing around with this df and found that if you changed the code to ...nfl_df['First Season'] = np.where(nfl_df['First Season'] > 1990, 1, nfl_df['Total Games']) then it replaces all values in First Season with values in Total Games, not just ones over 1990. Why would it do this? It doesn't seem very logical.

Answer (score 20):

```py
df.loc[df['First season'] > 1990, 'First Season'] = 1
```

Explanation:

`df.loc` takes two arguments, 'row index' and 'column index'. We are checking if the value is greater than 1990 of each row value, under "First season" column and then we replacing it with 1.

Answer (score 17):

```py
df['First Season'].loc[(df['First Season'] > 1990)] = 1
```

strange that nobody has this answer, the only missing part of your code is the ['First Season'] right after df and just remove your curly brackets inside.

Comment: That gives a 'SettingWithCopyWarning:'  It's better to use .loc for the entire thing like in EdChum's answer.

Answer (score 8):

**TLDR** — Here is some usage guidance, including some methods that haven't been mentioned yet:

| Use case | Recommended | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Speed** | [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) | `df.loc[df['A'] < 10, 'A'] = 1` |
| **Method chaining** | [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) | `df['A'] = df['A'].mask(df['A'] < 10, 1).method1().method2()` |
| **Whole dataframe** | [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) | `df = df.mask(df['A'] < 10, df**2)` |
| **Multiple conditions** | [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) | `df['A'] = np.select([df['A'] < 10, df['A'] > 20], [1, 2], default=df['A'])` |

## 1. Speed

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) if you have a large dataframe and are concerned about speed:

```
df.loc[df['Season'] > 1990, 'Season'] = 1
```

For small dataframes, speed is trivial, but technically there are faster options if you want:

[image]

<sup>*`df = pd.DataFrame({'Team': np.random.choice([*'ABCDEFG'], size=n), 'Season': np.random.randint(1900, 2001, size=n), 'Games': np.random.randint(0, 17, size=n)})`*</sup>

## 2. Method chaining

Use a `Series` method if you want to conditionally replace values within a method chain:

- [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) replaces values where the given condition is true

  ```
  df['Season'] = df['Season'].mask(df['Season'] > 1990, 1)
  ```
- [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) is just the inverted version (replace when false)

  ```
  df['Season'] = df['Season'].where(df['Season'] <= 1990, 1)
  ```

The chaining benefit is not obvious in OP's example but is very useful in other situations. Just as a toy example:

```
# compute average games per team, but pre-1972 games are weighted by half
df['Games'].mask(df['Season'] < 1972, 0.5*df['Games']).groupby(df['Team']).mean()
```

Practical examples:

- [`mask` certain values to 0 before grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70295514/13138364)
- [`mask` certain values as another column before filling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70223106/13138364)
- [select `where` a condition occurs before grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70073870/13138364)

## 3. Whole dataframe

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) if you want to conditionally replace values throughout the whole dataframe.

It's not easy to come up with a meaningful example given OP's sample, but here is a trivial example for demonstration:

```
# replace the given elements with the doubled value (or repeated string)
df.mask(df.isin(['Chicago Bears', 'Buffalo Bills', 8, 1990]), 2*df)
```

Practical example:

- [`mask` each row's maximum with its mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67408710/13138364)

## 4. Multiple conditions

Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) if you have multiple conditions, each with a different replacement:

```
# replace pre-1920 seasons with 0 and post-1990 seasons with 1
conditions = {
    0: df['Season'] < 1920,
    1: df['Season'] > 1990,
}
df['Season'] = np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys(), default=df['Season'])
```

Practical example:

- [replace values based on multiple regex conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953990/13138364)

Answer (score 6):

for single condition, ie. `( 'employrate'] > 70 )`

```
       country        employrate alcconsumption
0  Afghanistan  55.7000007629394            .03
1      Albania  51.4000015258789           7.29
2      Algeria              50.5            .69
3      Andorra                            10.17
4       Angola  75.6999969482422           5.57
```

use this:

```
df.loc[df['employrate'] > 70, 'employrate'] = 7
```

---

```
       country  employrate alcconsumption
0  Afghanistan   55.700001            .03
1      Albania   51.400002           7.29
2      Algeria   50.500000            .69
3      Andorra         nan          10.17
4       Angola    7.000000           5.57
```

therefore syntax here is:

```
df.loc[<mask>(here mask is generating the labels to index) , <optional column(s)> ]
```

---

For multiple conditions ie. `(df['employrate'] <=55) & (df['employrate'] > 50)`

use this:

```
df['employrate'] = np.where(
   (df['employrate'] <=55) & (df['employrate'] > 50) , 11, df['employrate']
   )
```

---

```
out[108]:
       country  employrate alcconsumption
0  Afghanistan   55.700001            .03
1      Albania   11.000000           7.29
2      Algeria   11.000000            .69
3      Andorra         nan          10.17
4       Angola   75.699997           5.57
```

therefore syntax here is:

```
 df['<column_name>'] = np.where((<filter 1> ) & (<filter 2>) , <new value>, df['column_name'])
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a list comprehension:

```
df['First Season'] = [1 if year > 1990 else year for year in df['First Season']]
```

Comment: This is the best option when you need to work directly on the value instead of using a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) which replaces the values where the condition is met:

```
df['First Season'].mask(lambda col: col > 1990, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can update the First Season column in df with the following syntax:

```
df['First Season'] = expression_for_new_values
```

To map the values in First Season we can use pandas‘ .map() method with the below syntax:

```
data_frame(['column']).map({'initial_value_1':'updated_value_1','initial_value_2':'updated_value_2'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from pandas 2.2.0 you can also use [`Series.case_when` to *replace values where the conditions are True.*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.case_when.html#pandas-series-case-when)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Team": ["Dallas Cowboys", "Chicago Bears", "Green Bay Packers"], "First Season": [1960, 1920, 1991]})
>>> df
                Team  First Season
0     Dallas Cowboys          1960
1      Chicago Bears          1920
2  Green Bay Packers          1991
>>> # caselist must be of the form (condition, replacement)
>>> df["First Season"].case_when(caselist=[(df["First Season"].gt(1990), 1)])
0    1960
1    1920
2       1
Name: First Season, dtype: int64
>>> 
>>> df["First Season"] = df["First Season"].case_when(caselist=[(df["First Season"].gt(1990), 1)])
>>> df
                Team  First Season
0     Dallas Cowboys          1960
1      Chicago Bears          1920
2  Green Bay Packers             1
>>>
```