# Conditional Substitution-Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame, where I want to apply filter in first column and then replace a number in 6th column with np.nan.

I also want to do these changes without taking the filter out of DataFrame. because I want the[image] changes to be part of same DataFrame.

For example. 
if ID=1, I want to replace "f" with np.nan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame: replace all values in a column, based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition)

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want, but I suggest you read up on [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

```
df.loc[df['ID'] == 1, 'f'] = np.nan
```