# replace all values in a column, based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a similar problem to this question [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition). However, I need to replace values in the same column given different conditions. Something like the code below

```
for item in items:
    df.loc[df['A'] == item,'A'] = 'other'
```

where items is a list with different strings that I need to replace with 'other' in column 'A'. The thing is that my dataframe is very large and this approach is very slow. Is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to index by a single Boolean series:

```
df.loc[df['A'].isin(items), 'A'] = 'other'
```

The bottleneck in your logic is `df['A'] == item` in a loop. The above method ensures only a single Boolean series is calculated for indexing.