# How to replace values greater than specific value in dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with some outlier in the age field here is the unique values of my data sorted

```
unique = df_csv['AGE'].unique()
print (sorted(unique))
```

[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 79, 126, 140, 149, 152, 228, 235, 267]

How can I replace any value greater than 80 with the mean or median of my Age column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to work with a column in a dataframe, you should resolve to `loc`:

```
 # replace `median` with `mean` if you want
 df_csv.loc[df_csv['AGE']>80,'AGE'] = df_csv['AGE'].median()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
series[series > 80] = series.median()
print(series)
```

**Output**

```
0     21
1     22
2     23
3     24
4     25
      ..
58    52
59    52
60    52
61    52
62    52
Length: 63, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
median = df_csv['AGE'].median()
# using apply 
df_csv['AGE'].apply(lambda x: median if x>80 else x)
```

Other method:  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition)

Comment: To explain what apply does : lambda is a function without a name, that you could assign to it any function (similar to def ... but easier to use). 
lambda x, means select the value from the dataframe.
then after the semi colon you have the condition:
median if x>80, else keep x the same 
it goes over every row and does this check