# How can I modify data column values with pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

### Need to change the values of city into Pune expect Bangalore.

sample input Data:

```
 EmployeeId     city     join_month
0   001        Mumbai        1
1   001        Bangalore     3
2   002        Pune          2
3   002        Mumbai        6
4   003        Delhi         9
5   003        Mumbai        12
6   004        Bangalore     11
7   004        Pune          10
8   005        Mumbai         5
```

Output sample:

```
 EmployeeId    city     join_month
0   001        Pune          1
1   001        Bangalore     3
2   002        Pune          2
3   002        Pune          6
4   003        Pune          9
5   003        Pune          12
6   004        Bangalore     11
7   004        Pune          10
8   005        Pune          5
```

Comment: maybe you should add an output sample to help people understanding it.

Comment: All sorts of options from [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame: replace all values in a column, based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `np.where` will be work.

1. find the city is eq `Bangalore`
2. if the city is `Bangalore` not change, else change to `Pune`.

```
cond = df['city'] == 'Bangalore'
df['city'] = np.where(cond, 'Bangalore', 'Pune')
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have a data frame already. Using pandas, you can modify columns like this:

You can look at your columns using:

```
df.columns
```

To change the column names:

```
df.columns = ["Employee_ID", "City", "Month_Joined"
```

To change a single value in your `city` column, you can use the code below for each city value you want to change. `0` is the row, `city` is the column name, and `Pune` is what you want to change it to:

```
df.loc[0, "city"] = "Pune"
```

To change multiple values to in the `city` column to a single value. You are accessing the column `city` and replacing all occurrences of `Mumbai` and `Delhi` with Pune.

```
cityChange = df["city"] = df["city"].replace(["Mumbai", "Delhi"], "Pune")
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have 802 rows and different values in the column. It might be difficult to change them one by one. Is their any other technique? @live405

Comment: Arguably the question is 1) how to *locate* other cities 2) how to change them to `"Pune"`. You have answered only the 2nd.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I have done it before but don’t have the code on me.  I will work on it tomorrow if is not already solved by then, sorry I couldn’t help :)

Comment: I have update my answer, I hope that it helps.