# Replace maximum value of each row with mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace maximum value for each row in the column with `mean` value for this row. the method i am using taking a lot of time for complete. i am using pandas `DataFrame`. replaced mean value need to be an integer but with correct flood division.`example: if value is 3.2 then 3 or if value is 3.8 then 4.`

**my slow solution:**

```
for j in range(0,len(df_train)):
    val = df_train.iloc[j,1:51].mean()
    m = df_train.iloc[j,1:51].max()
    df_train.iloc[j,1:51] = df_train.iloc[j,1:51].replace(m,int(val))
```

**My DataFrame:**

| id | feature0 | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | feature4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | 21 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

**Output i want:**

| id | feature0 | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | feature4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | `2` |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 0 | `3` |
| 2 | 1 | `5` | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | `3` | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df.values[range(len(df.index)), np.argmax(df.values, axis=1)] = df.mean(axis=1).round()
```

`np.argmax` over the rows tells us position of each maximum value per row. Then we use fancy indexing into `df.values` and assign the `mean` values over the rows (`axis=1`) but `round`ed.

to get

```
    feature0  feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4
id
0          0         0         3         1         2
1          4         0         4         0         3
2          1         5         4         0         0
3          0         3         0         0         2
```

Comment: It giving me error. of  `'>'  not supported between instance of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: @Niro Then before doing above, can you do `df = df.set_index("id").astype(int)`? This will keep `id` column aside and make sure the values are integers.

Comment: Although this method solved the problem but my id columns filled with `nan`.

Comment: @Niro You did use `df = df.set_index("id").astype(int)`, right?

Comment: @Niro Then you have more than 1 `id` column in the data?

Comment: @Niro, then you can do `df.index = range(len(df.index))` at the end to get back the index..

Comment: @Niro and it didn't reset?

Comment: @Niro maybe you can restart kernel `:)`

Comment: sorry it was my bad. your solution was fine all along.

Comment: huh, i didn't realize you could assign into `df.values`, interesting

Comment: @tdy do you happen to know if there is a way to do it over `df` itself? There is `df.lookup` for this kind of indexing I believe, but its result is not assignable..

Comment: @MustafaAydın only way i know is to melt/groupby/pivot. it's much more verbose than this `.values` method, but i posted the code just in case anyone's interested i guess

Comment: @MustafaAydın Just in case you're still interested, I realized it actually is possible to do this over `df` itself via `df.mask`.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you happen to know if there is a way to do it over `df` itself (instead of the `df.values` numpy array)?

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(
    df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0), # the mask (True locations will get replaced)
    df.mean(axis=1).round(),       # the replacements
    axis=0)                        # replace by rows (each replacement value corresponds to one mask row)

#    feature0  feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4
# 0         0         0         3         1         2
# 1         4         0         4         0         3
# 2         1         5         4         0         0
# 3         0         3         0         0         2
```

Advantages of [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

- can handle ties (whereas the numpy approach will only replace the first one if tied)
- can chain with other methods (whereas the numpy approach forces you to modify in place)

For reference, the boolean mask:

```
df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)

#    feature0  feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4
# 0     False     False     False     False      True
# 1     False     False     False     False      True
# 2     False      True     False     False     False
# 3     False      True     False     False     False
```

---

Note: To replace the *column* max by *column* mean, just swap all the `axis` params:

```
df.mask(
    df.eq(df.max(axis=0), axis=1),
    df.mean(axis=0).round(),
    axis=1)

#    feature0  feature1  feature2  feature3  feature4
# 0         0         0         3         1         5
# 1         1         0         4         0         4
# 2         1         8         4         0         0
# 3         0        11         0         0         2
```

Comment: Order of columns spoiled a bit,but it also worked.

Comment: @Sudhanshu FYI it turns out pandas has a built-in way of handling this via `df.mask` (answer updated). This is much more idiomatic and also doesn't reorder the columns anymore.