# Fillna by relating multiple columns using a function

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

> I have 3 columns in the dataframe. object, id and price. I want fill
> the blanks by reading the id column and discover which price should I
> use.  For exemple: If the id ends in (A,B or C) the price should be 30
> but if it's end (7A,7B or 7C) the price should be 50,   If the id ends
> in (E,F or G) the price should be 20, If the id ends in (O,M or N),
> the price should be 10.
>
> Here is the dataframe:

```
    object    id  price
0   laptop   24A   30
1   laptop   37C   NaN
2   laptop   21O   NaN
3   laptop   17C   50
4   laptop   55A   30
5   laptop   34N   NaN
6   laptop   05E   20
7   laptop   29B   NaN
8   laptop   22M   10
9   laptop   62F   NaN
10  laptop   23G   20
11  laptop   61O   NaN
12  laptop   27A   NaN
```

> Expected output:

```
    object    id  price
0   laptop   24A   30
1   laptop   37C   50
2   laptop   21O   10
3   laptop   17C   50
4   laptop   55A   30
5   laptop   34N   10
6   laptop   05E   20
7   laptop   29B   30
8   laptop   22M   10
9   laptop   62F   20
10  laptop   23G   20
11  laptop   61O   10
12  laptop   27A   50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`np.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [**`str.contains`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) conditions:

```
conditions = {
    30: df.id.str.contains('[^7][ABC]$'),
    50: df.id.str.contains('7[ABC]$'),
    20: df.id.str.contains('[EFG]$'),
    10: df.id.str.contains('[OMN]$'),
}
df.price = np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys())

#     object   id  price
# 0   laptop  24A     30
# 1   laptop  37C     50
# 2   laptop  21O     10
# 3   laptop  17C     50
# 4   laptop  55A     30
# 5   laptop  34N     10
# 6   laptop  05E     20
# 7   laptop  29B     30
# 8   laptop  22M     10
# 9   laptop  62F     20
# 10  laptop  23G     20
# 11  laptop  61O     10
# 12  laptop  27A     50
```

You could also use `loc` masking if you want to use [**`fillna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
for price, condition in conditions.items():
    df.loc[condition, 'price'] = df.loc[condition, 'price'].fillna(price)
```

---

#### Update 1

If you want to further restrict by `df.object`, you can add the `df.object` condition with `&`:

```
conditions = {
    30: df.object.eq('laptop') & df.id.str.contains('[^7][ABC]$'),
    50: df.object.eq('laptop') & df.id.str.contains('7[ABC]$'),
    20: df.object.eq('laptop') & df.id.str.contains('[EFG]$'),
    10: df.object.eq('laptop') & df.id.str.contains('[OMN]$'),
    1000: df.object.eq('phone') & df.id.str.contains('[OMN]$'),
}
```

---

#### Update 2

If you really want to use a function, you can [**`apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) along rows (`axis=1`), but row-apply is much slower and not advised when you have vectorized options like `np.select`:

```
def price(row):
    result = np.nan
    if row.object == 'laptop':
        if row.id[-2:] in ['7A', '7B', '7C']:
            result = 50
        elif row.id[-1] in list('ABC'):
            result = 30
        elif row.id[-1] in list('EFG'):
            result = 20
        elif row.id[-1] in list('OMN'):
            result = 10
    elif row.object == 'phone':
        if row.id[-2:] in ['7A', '7B', '7C']:
            result = 5000
        ...
    return result
df.price = df.apply(price, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks man! But There is another way to fill the blank spaces from a function that I created?FOR EXAMPLE IF I DON'T HAVE ONLY LAPTOP IN THE OBJECT, I HAVE ANOTHER PRODUCT WOULD HAVE TO CREATE ANOTHER TYPE OF CONDITION FOR THAT CATEGORY.

Comment: @HarryJones see if the last edit is what you want. for example if you want "phone" objects ending in "OMN" to be 1000, that condition would be: `1000: df.object.eq('phone') & df.id.str.contains('[OMN]$'),`

Comment: i also added a `df.apply` option if you really want to use a conversion function, but `np.select` is much faster