# How to reset cumulative sum per group when a certain column is 0 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have following dataframe in which I want to make a cumulative sum on a certain column (`Value`), together with a group by on field `Group`, but reset that cumulative sum to 0 when a value in another column (`Quantity`) is 0.

| Group | Quantity | Value | Cumulative_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 200 | 200 |
| B | 5 | 300 | 300 |
| A | 1 | 50 | 250 |
| A | 0 | 100 | 0 |
| C | 5 | 400 | 400 |
| A | 10 | 300 | 300 |
| B | 10 | 200 | 500 |
| A | 15 | 350 | 650 |

I have tried working with blocks like in the code below, but the issue is that it doesn't do the cumulative sum correctly:

```
blocks = df['Quantity'].eq(0)[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]

df['temp_field'] = (df.groupby(['Group', blocks])
   ['Value'].cumsum()
   .where(df['Quantity']!=0,df['Value'])
)

df['Cumulative_sum'] = np.where(df['Quantity'] == 0, 0, df['temp_field'])
```

Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For the given resetting `condition`, use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) to create a `Reset` grouper that tells us when `Quantity` hits 0 within each `Group`:

   ```
   condition = df.Quantity.eq(0)
   df['Reset'] = condition.groupby(df.Group).cumsum()

   #   Group  Quantity  Value  Cumulative_sum  Reset
   # 0     A        10    200             200      0
   # 1     B         5    300             300      0
   # 2     A         1     50             250      0
   # 3     A         0    100               0      1
   # 4     C         5    400             400      0
   # 5     A        10    300             300      1
   # 6     B        10    200             500      0
   # 7     A        15    350             650      1
   ```
2. [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the `Value` column whenever the resetting `condition` is met and use another [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) on both `Group` and `Reset`:

   ```
   df['Cumul'] = df.Value.mask(condition, 0).groupby([df.Group, df.Reset]).cumsum()

   #   Group  Quantity  Value  Cumulative_sum  Reset  Cumul
   # 0     A        10    200             200      0    200
   # 1     B         5    300             300      0    300
   # 2     A         1     50             250      0    250
   # 3     A         0    100               0      1      0
   # 4     C         5    400             400      0    400
   # 5     A        10    300             300      1    300
   # 6     B        10    200             500      0    500
   # 7     A        15    350             650      1    650
   ```

Comment: The only answer that worked well for me with groupings