# How to replace a specific value on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

started learning Python for data science a few weeks ago, and ran into this problem for my own project. I'm trying to replace gaming publisher name to "Other" if the count is below 5. When I use .mask() function, however, it seems to also replace the "Count" value to "Other" as well. Any possible way to just change the "Publisher" value to "Other" and keep the "Count" value as it is?

The method I tried is below:

````
publisher_subset = data.filter(['Publisher'])
df = publisher_subset.value_counts().reset_index(name='Counts')
df.mask(df["Counts"] <= 5, "Other", inplace=False)
```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOzFY.png)`
````

Comment: Here's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np    
df['Publisher'] = np.where(df["Counts"] <= 5, "Other", df['Publisher'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .loc[] indexer to selectively apply the mask to the Publisher column only.

```
publisher_subset = data.filter(['Publisher'])
df = publisher_subset.value_counts().reset_index(name='Counts')

df.loc[df["Counts"] <= 5, "Publisher"] = "Other"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mask` if you select only the `Publisher` column:

```
# Select publisher column only to mask values
rename_others = lambda x: x['Publisher'].mask(x['counts'] <= 5, other='Others')

out = (df.value_counts('Publisher').reset_index(name='counts')
         .assign(Publisher=rename_others))
print(out)

# Output
  Publisher  counts
0      Sony       7
1    Bandai       6
2    Others       5
3    Others       5
4    Others       5
5    Others       4
6    Others       4
```

I suppose you also want to sum by `Publisher`:

```
out = (df.value_counts('Publisher').reset_index(name='counts')
         .assign(Publisher=rename_others)
         .groupby('Publisher', sort=False, as_index=False).sum())

  Publisher  counts
0      Sony       7
1    Bandai       6
2    Others      23
```